# using nested class within class doesnt works in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have included nested class within a class to use it in a view but it doesnt show up the properties of that nested class below is the class, I want to use sku in the view :
View:

```
@model Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.CategoryModel
<div class="product-item">
<h2 class="product-title">
@Model.Name
 </h2>

<div class="description">
      **@Model.ProductVariantModels.Select(x => x.Sku)//doesnt works** // partial class productvariant

</div>
<div class="add-info">
@Model.Name <br/> @Model.FullDescription //values from class CategoryModel 
  </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class CategoryModel : BaseEntityModel
{
    public CategoryModel()
    {
        ProductVariantModels = new List<ProductVariantModel>();
    }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string FullDescription { get; set; }
public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
public IList<ProductVariantModel> ProductVariantModels { get; set; }

public class ProductVariantModel : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool ShowSku { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a nested class, not a partial class.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 4):

`ProductVariantModels` is a `List`. You have to enumerate the `List`.

```
@foreach (var pvModel in Model.ProductVariantModels) {
   @pvModel.Sku
}
```

Comment: @if(Model.ProductVariantModels.Count > 0)
    { foreach (var sku in Model.ProductVariantModels) {@sku.Sku } }

Comment: According to the `CategoryModel ` class, it doesn't have a `Sku` property. only `ProductVariantModel` has a `Sku`.

Comment: yeh i want to use that property

Answer (score 0):

*If you're using `HtmlHelpers`*, you have to use a `for` loop with an index rather than a `foreach` loop.

As [explained really well here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894442/mvc-razor-view-nested-foreachs-model/8896840#8896840), the automatic model binding expects field input names to have a 'dot' notation like `Property.SubProperty.SubSub...` to match the instance properties when assigning -- but if you render them in a `foreach` loop they won't have the full expression, and thus won't output the full 'dot' notation.

Also see [MVC 4 binding nested list of lists result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009603/mvc-4-binding-nested-list-of-lists-result)