# MVC Razor view nested foreach's model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

Imagine a common scenario, this is a simpler version of what I'm coming across.  I actually have a couple of layers of further nesting on mine....

But this is the scenario

Theme contains List
Category contains List
Product contains List

My Controller provides a fully populated Theme, with all the Categories for that theme, the Products within this categories and the their orders.

The orders collection has a property called Quantity (amongst many others) that needs to be editable.

```
@model ViewModels.MyViewModels.Theme

@Html.LabelFor(Model.Theme.name)
@foreach (var category in Model.Theme)
{
   @Html.LabelFor(category.name)
   @foreach(var product in theme.Products)
   {
      @Html.LabelFor(product.name)
      @foreach(var order in product.Orders)
      {
          @Html.TextBoxFor(order.Quantity)
          @Html.TextAreaFor(order.Note)
          @Html.EditorFor(order.DateRequestedDeliveryFor)
      }
   }
}
```

If I use lambda instead then then I only seem to get a reference to the top Model object, "Theme" not those within the foreach loop.

Is what I'm trying to do there even possible or have I overestimated or misunderstood what is possible?

With the above I get an error on the TextboxFor, EditorFor, etc

> CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `@` before all `foreach`s? Shouldn't you also have lambdas in `Html.EditorFor` (`Html.EditorFor(m => m.Note)`, for example) and the rest of the methods? I may be mistaking, but can you please paste your actual code? I'm pretty new to MVC, but you can solve it rather easily with partial views, or editors (if that is the name?).

Comment: `category.name` I'm sure it's a `string` and `...For` does not support a string as the first parameter

Comment: yes, I just missed the @'s, now added. Thanks.
However, as for lambda, if I start to type @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.  
then I only seem to get a reference to the top Model object, not those within the foreach loop.

Comment: @DavidC - I don't know enough of MVC 3 to answer yet - but I suspect that is your problem `:)`.

Comment: I'm on the train, but if this isn't answered by the time I get to work ill post an answer. The quick answer is to use a regular `for()` rather than a `foreach`. I'll explain why, cause it confused the hell out of me for a long time too.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, so you can then use: LabelFor(m => m.Theme[0].name), etc.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

The quick answer is to use a `for()` loop in place of your `foreach()` loops. Something like:

```
@for(var themeIndex = 0; themeIndex < Model.Theme.Count(); themeIndex++)
{
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Theme[themeIndex])

   @for(var productIndex=0; productIndex < Model.Theme[themeIndex].Products.Count(); productIndex++)
   {
      @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Theme[themeIndex].Products[productIndex].name)
      @for(var orderIndex=0; orderIndex < Model.Theme[themeIndex].Products[productIndex].Orders; orderIndex++)
      {
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Theme[themeIndex].Products[productIndex].Orders[orderIndex].Quantity)
          @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Theme[themeIndex].Products[productIndex].Orders[orderIndex].Note)
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Theme[themeIndex].Products[productIndex].Orders[orderIndex].DateRequestedDeliveryFor)
      }
   }
}
```

But this glosses over *why* this fixes the problem.

There are three things that you have at least a cursory understanding before you can resolve this issue. I have 
to admit that I [cargo-culted](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CargocultProgramming.aspx) this
for a long time when I started working with the framework. And it took me quite a while
to really get what was going on.

Those three things are:

- How do the `LabelFor` and other `...For` helpers work in MVC?
- What is an Expression Tree?
- How does the Model Binder work?

All three of these concepts link together to get an answer.

### How do the `LabelFor` and other `...For` helpers work in MVC?

So, you've used the `HtmlHelper<T>` extensions for `LabelFor` and `TextBoxFor` and others, and
you probably noticed that when you invoke them, you pass them a lambda and it *magically* generates
some html. But how?

So the first thing to notice is the signature for these helpers. Lets look at the simplest overload for
`TextBoxFor`

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
)
```

First, this is an extension method for a strongly typed `HtmlHelper`, of type `<TModel>`. So, to simply 
state what happens behind the scenes, when razor renders this view it generates a class.
Inside of this class is an instance of `HtmlHelper<TModel>` (as the property `Html`, which is why you can use `@Html...`),
where `TModel` is the type defined in your `@model` statement. So in your case, when you are looking at this view `TModel`
will always be of the type `ViewModels.MyViewModels.Theme`.

Now, the next argument is a bit tricky. So lets look at an invocation

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.SomeProperty);
```

It looks like we have a little lambda, And if one were to guess the signature, one might think that the type for
this argument would simply be a `Func<TModel, TProperty>`, where `TModel` is the type of the view model and `TProperty`
is inferred as the type of the property.

But thats not quite right, if you look at the *actual* type of the argument its `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`.

So when you normally generate a lambda, the compiler takes the lambda and compiles it down into MSIL, just like any other 
function (which is why you can use delegates, method groups, and lambdas more or less interchangeably, because they are just
code references.)

However, when the compiler sees that the type is an `Expression<>`, it doesn't immediately compile the lambda down to MSIL, instead it generates an
Expression Tree!

### What is an [Expression Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)?

So, what the heck is an expression tree. Well, it's not complicated but its not a walk in the park either. To quote ms:

| Expression trees represent code in a tree-like data structure, where each node is an expression, for example, a method call or a binary operation such as x < y.

Simply put, an expression tree is a representation of a function as a collection of "actions".

In the case of `model=>model.SomeProperty`, the expression tree would have a node in it that says: "Get 'Some Property' from a 'model'"

This expression tree can be *compiled* into a function that can be invoked, but as long as it's an expression tree, it's just a collection of nodes.

### So what is that good for?

So `Func<>` or `Action<>`, once you have them, they are pretty much atomic. All you can really do is `Invoke()` them, aka tell them to 
do the work they are supposed to do.

`Expression<Func<>>` on the other hand, represents a collection of actions, which can be appended, manipulated, [visited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx), or [compiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx) and invoked.

### So why are you telling me all this?

So with that understanding of what an `Expression<>` is, we can go back to `Html.TextBoxFor`. When it renders a textbox, it needs
to generate a few things *about* the property that you are giving it. Things like `attributes` on the property for validation, and specifically
in this case it needs to figure out what to *name* the `<input>` tag.

It does this by "walking" the expression tree and building a name. So for an expression like `model=>model.SomeProperty`, it walks the expression
gathering the properties that you are asking for and builds `<input name='SomeProperty'>`.

For a more complicated example, like `model=>model.Foo.Bar.Baz.FooBar`, it might generate `<input name="Foo.Bar.Baz.FooBar" value="[whatever FooBar is]" />`

Make sense? It is not just the work that the `Func<>` does, but *how* it does its work is important here.

(Note other frameworks like LINQ to SQL do similar things by walking an expression tree and building a different grammar, that this case a SQL query)

### How does the Model Binder work?

So once you get that, we have to briefly talk about the model binder. When the form gets posted, it's simply like a flat
`Dictionary<string, string>`, we have lost the hierarchical structure our nested view model may have had. It's the 
model binder's job to take this key-value pair combo and attempt to rehydrate an object with some properties. How does it do 
this? You guessed it, by using the "key" or name of the input that got posted.

So if the form post looks like

```
Foo.Bar.Baz.FooBar = Hello
```

And you are posting to a model called `SomeViewModel`, then it does the reverse of what the helper did in the first place. It looks for 
a property called "Foo". Then it looks for a property called "Bar" off of "Foo", then it looks for "Baz"... and so on...

Finally it tries to parse the value into the type of "FooBar" and assign it to "FooBar".

*PHEW!!!*

And voila, you have your model. The instance the Model Binder just constructed gets handed into requested Action.

---

So your solution doesn't work because the `Html.[Type]For()` helpers need an expression. And you are just giving them a value. It has no idea
what the context is for that value, and it doesn't know what to do with it.

Now some people suggested using partials to render. Now this in theory will work, but probably not the way that you expect. When you render a partial, you are changing the type of `TModel`, because you are in a different view context. This means that you can describe
your property with a shorter expression. It also means when the helper generates the name for your expression, it will be shallow. It
will only generate based on the expression it's given (not the entire context).

So lets say you had a partial that just rendered "Baz" (from our example before). Inside that partial you could just say:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.FooBar)
```

Rather than

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Foo.Bar.Baz.FooBar)
```

That means that it will generate an input tag like this:

```
<input name="FooBar" />
```

Which, if you are posting this form to an action that is expecting a large deeply nested ViewModel, then it will try to hydrate a property
called `FooBar` off of `TModel`. Which at best isn't there, and at worst is something else entirely. If you were posting to a specific action that was accepting a `Baz`, rather than the root model, then this would work great! In fact, partials are a good way to change your view context, for example if you had a page with multiple forms that all post to different actions, then rendering a partial for each one would be a great idea.

---

Now once you get all of this, you can start to do really interesting things with `Expression<>`, by programatically extending them and doing
other neat things with them. I won't get into any of that. But, hopefully, this will
give you a better understanding of what is going on behind the scenes and why things are acting the way that they are.

Comment: Awesome reply. I'm currently trying to digest it. :)
Also guilty of Cargo Culting!  Like that description.

Comment: Need more than one upvote for this. +3 (one for each explanation), and +1 for Cargo-Cultists. Absolutely brilliant answer!

Comment: This is why I love SO: short answer + in-depth explanation + awesome link (cargo-cult). I will like to show the post about cargo-cult to anyone who doesn't think that knowledge about inner workings of stuff is extremely important!

Answer (score 19):

You can simply use EditorTemplates to do that, you need to create a directory named "EditorTemplates" in your controller's view folder and place a seperate view for each of your nested entities (named as entity class name)

Main view :

```
@model ViewModels.MyViewModels.Theme

@Html.LabelFor(Model.Theme.name)
@Html.EditorFor(Model.Theme.Categories)
```

Category view (/MyController/EditorTemplates/Category.cshtml) :

```
@model ViewModels.MyViewModels.Category

@Html.LabelFor(Model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(Model.Products)
```

Product view (/MyController/EditorTemplates/Product.cshtml) :

```
@model ViewModels.MyViewModels.Product

@Html.LabelFor(Model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(Model.Orders)
```

and so on

this way Html.EditorFor helper will generate element's names in an ordered manner and therefore you won't have any further problem for retrieving the posted Theme entity as a whole

Comment: While the accepted answer is a very good one (I also upvoted it), this answer is the more maintainable option.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a Category partial and a Product partial, each would take a smaller part of the main model as it's own model, i.e. Category's model type might be an IEnumerable, you would pass in Model.Theme to it.  The Product's partial might be an IEnumerable that you pass Model.Products into (from within the Category partial).

I'm not sure if that would be the right way forward, but would be interested in knowing.

**EDIT**

Since posting this answer, I've used EditorTemplates and find this the easiest way to handle repeating input groups or items.  It handles all your validation message problems and form submission/model binding woes automatically.

Comment: That had occurred to me, just wasn't sure how it would handle it when I read it back to update.

Comment: It's close, but since this is a form to be posted as a unit it won't work quite right. Once inside the partial the view context has changed and it no longer has the deeply nested expression. Posting back to the `Theme` model wouldn't get hydrated properly.

Comment: That's my concern too.  I would usually do the above as a read only approach to displaying the products and then provide a link on each product to maybe a /Product/Edit/123 action method to edit each one on it's own form.  I think you can become undone trying to do too much on one page in MVC.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips yes it is very possible that I have.  I came from a Forms background, so I still can't always get used to the idea of having to leave the page to make an edit. :(

Answer (score 2):

When you are using foreach loop within view for binded model ...
Your  model is supposed to be in listed format.

i.e

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModels.MyViewModels>


        @{
            if (Model.Count() > 0)
            {            

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Theme.FirstOrDefault().name)
                @foreach (var theme in Model.Theme)
                {
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => theme.name)
                   @foreach(var product in theme.Products)
                   {
                      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.name)
                      @foreach(var order in product.Orders)
                      {
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => order.Quantity)
                         @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => order.Note)
                          @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => order.DateRequestedDeliveryFor)
                      }
                  }
                }
            }else{
                   <span>No Theam avaiable</span>
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am surprised that code above even compiles. @Html.LabelFor requires a FUNC operation as parameter, yours is not

Comment: I don't know whether the code above compile or not, but **nested @foreach works** for me. MVC5.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the error.

The HtmlHelpers appended with "For" expects lambda expression as a parameter.

If you are passing the value directly, better use Normal one.

e.g.

Instead of TextboxFor(....) use Textbox()

syntax for TextboxFor will be like Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Property)

In your scenario you can use basic for loop, as it will give you index to use.

```
@for(int i=0;i<Model.Theme.Count;i++)
 {
   @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Theme[i].name)
   @for(int j=0;j<Model.Theme[i].Products.Count;j++) )
     {
      @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Theme[i].Products[j].name)
      @for(int k=0;k<Model.Theme[i].Products[j].Orders.Count;k++)
          {
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.Theme[i].Products[j].Orders[k].Quantity)
           @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>Model.Theme[i].Products[j].Orders[k].Note)
           @Html.EditorFor(m=>Model.Theme[i].Products[j].Orders[k].DateRequestedDeliveryFor)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another much simpler possibility is that one of your property names is wrong (probably one you just changed in the class).  This is what it was for me in RazorPages .NET Core 3.