# Getting a value from a model within a model using razor in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am having an issue on how to a value out of a model within a model and accessing it in razor.  I have this model Problems that contains a model called Types.  How would I go about accessing values from Type through Problems in razor.  It would look something like this, but obviously this does not work?

This is how I call the model in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Problems>
```

trying to access Type values in this model that hold Types.

Here is my model where I am trying to access the values:

```
public class Problems
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Type> Types {get; set;}

    }
```

This is my other model I am trying to access the values from:

```
public partial class Type
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

So something I would try and do would look like this, but this obviously doesn't work.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type.Description())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access like this:

```
@{

foreach(var item in Model)
{
  if(item.Types.Count() > 0)
  {
    foreach(var innerItem in item.Types)
    {

    }
 }


}

}
```

Comment: I see.... using nested foreach loops.  How would I call it in the razor tag?@Html.DisplayNameFor(inneritem => inneritem.Title).  But it wont let me use the same name?

Comment: refer thiss one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894442/mvc-razor-view-nested-foreachs-model